# Visual Studio C++ unit testing (unmanaged)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm setting up a unit test suite for some unmanaged C++ code, and I've got some questions.

## Setup

I added the project to my solution with `Visual C++` → `Test` → `Native Unit Test Project`.

[image: Native Unit Test Project creation]

## Code

In order to figure out how things are grouped in this test framework, and what initialization runs when, I replaced the content of the source file (`unittest1.cpp`) with a modified version of the `USAGE EXAMPLE` from the top of CppUnitTest.h:

```
#include <CppUnitTest.h>
#include <string>

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
using std::string;

BEGIN_TEST_MODULE_ATTRIBUTE()
TEST_MODULE_ATTRIBUTE(L"Date", L"2010/6/12")
END_TEST_MODULE_ATTRIBUTE()


static string Indent("");

void openBlock()
{
    Logger::WriteMessage((Indent + "{").c_str());
    Indent += "  ";
}

void closeBlock()
{
    Indent.resize(Indent.size() >= 2 ? (Indent.size() - 2) : 0);
    Logger::WriteMessage((Indent + "}").c_str());
}


TEST_MODULE_INITIALIZE(ModuleInitialize)
{
    Logger::WriteMessage((Indent + "In Module Initialize").c_str());
    openBlock();
}

TEST_MODULE_CLEANUP(ModuleCleanup)
{
    closeBlock();
    Logger::WriteMessage((Indent + "In Module Cleanup").c_str());
}



TEST_CLASS(Class1)
{
public:
    Class1()
    {
        Logger::WriteMessage((Indent + "In Class1").c_str());
        openBlock();
    }
    ~Class1()
    {
        closeBlock();
        Logger::WriteMessage((Indent + "In ~Class1").c_str());
    }



    TEST_CLASS_INITIALIZE(ClassInitialize)
    {
        Logger::WriteMessage((Indent + "In Class Initialize").c_str());
        openBlock();
    }
    TEST_CLASS_CLEANUP(ClassCleanup)
    {
        closeBlock();
        Logger::WriteMessage((Indent + "In Class Cleanup").c_str());
    }


    BEGIN_TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE(Method1)
        TEST_OWNER(L"OwnerName")
        TEST_PRIORITY(1)
        END_TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE()

    TEST_METHOD(Method1)
    {
        Logger::WriteMessage((Indent + "In Method1").c_str());
        Assert::AreEqual(0, 0);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Method2)
    {
        Logger::WriteMessage((Indent + "In Method2").c_str());
        Assert::Fail(L"Fail");
        Logger::WriteMessage("This won't print due to failure above.");
    }
};
```

## Output

It generated the output below. (I added some linebreaks for clarity.)

```
In Module Initialize
{

  In Class Initialize
  {

    In Class1
    {
      In Method1
    }
    In ~Class1

    In Class1
    {
      In Method2
    }
    In ~Class1

  }
  In Class Cleanup

}
In Module Cleanup
```

## Inferences

From this I infer:

- Each `TEST_MODULE` contains zero or more `TEST_CLASS`es.
- Each `TEST_CLASS` contains zero or more `TEST_METHOD`s.
- `TEST_MODULE_INITIALIZE()` and  `TEST_MODULE_CLEANUP()` are run once for each `TEST_MODULE`, before/after its series of `TEST_CLASS`es are executed.
- `TEST_CLASS_INITIALIZE()` and `TEST_CLASS_CLEANUP()` are run once for each `TEST_CLASS`, before/after its series of `TEST_METHOD`s are executed.
- Each `TEST_METHOD` is an instance of a `TEST_CLASS`. The class constructor is executed immediately before the `TEST_METHOD()`, and the class destructor is executed immediately after the `TEST_METHOD()`.

## Questions

1. Are my inferences above all correct? Have I missed anything important?
2. Should/must I always have one and only one `TEST_MODULE` per source file? Can a `TEST_MODULE` be split among multiple source files? What is best practice?
3. May I have more than one `TEST_CLASS` per file or `TEST_MODULE`? Are there best practices in this regard?
4. What is the purpose of `ATTRIBUTE`s? How are they used?
5. What is the name of this unit test framework? What search terms can I use to learn more?

Comment: The name of this framework is **[Microsoft Unit Testing Framework for C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh598953.aspx)**. Under the link you will find some basic information about it.